# count the number of occurrences of a pattern in many rows of a column file

Tags: perl

i have a column file as below

```
np  np  n_nom   3   {RP}    {RP}

paNiyappeVttirunna  VM_RP   V_RP    o   o   o

np  np  n_nom   -3  {/RP}   {/RP}
```

and the next few lines are...

```
np   np n_nom   3   {RP}    {RP}


paNiya      VM_RP     V_RP    o  o   o

np  np  n_nom   -3  {/RP}
```

and the file goes on like this.

I want to count the umber .of parts of the file that has {RP} {RP} and {/RP} {/RP} occurring together.

Answer (score 1):

This is done very simply using backreferences in the regular expression

The program below searches for any occurrence of `{RP}` or `{/RP}` followed by some whitespace and the same string again

It expects the data file as a command line parameter

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count;

while (<>) {
  $count++ if m|(\{/?RP\})\s+\1|;
}

print "$count occurrences";
```

**output**

```
3 occurrences
```

---

**Update**

Your description of the problem is very unclear but I have done my best at reinterpreting it. This code looks for all cases where a line containing `{/RP} <some whitespace> {/RP}` is followed immediately by a line containing `{RP} <some whitespace> {RP}`. All blank input lines are ignored

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @pair;
my $count;

while (<>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  push @pair, $_;
  next unless @pair >= 2;
  shift @pair while @pair > 2;
  if ($pair[0] =~ m|\{/RP\}\s+\{/RP\}| and $pair[1] =~ m|\{RP\}\s+\{RP\}|) {
    $count++;
    @pair = ();
  }
}

print "$count occurrences\n";
```

**output**

```
1 occurrences
```

---

**Update**

OK lets try again. This program checks the third and fourth whitespace-separated columns of every line. Whenever it sees a pair of `{RP}` it sets `$depth` to `1`, and Whenever it sees a pair of `{/RP}` it sets $depth it to zero, incrementing `$count` if `$depth` was previously non-zero

Note that all lines containing only a single `{RP}` or `{/RP}` are simply ignored. It is impossible to tell from your description what action you want in this circumstance

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $depth;
my $count = 0;

while (<>) {
  my @fields = map $_ // '', (split)[4,5];
  if (grep($_ eq '{RP}', @fields) == 2) {
    $depth = 1;
  }
  elsif (grep($_ eq '{/RP}', @fields) == 2) {
    $count++ if $depth;
    $depth = 0;
  }
}

print "$count occurrences\n";
```

**output**

```
1 occurrences
```

Comment: <p>This code will count the total occurances of {RP} and {/RP} but i wanted both the string occuring together as a single count.so in the above file the count should be 1 since they occur together in array[4] and array[5] only once

Comment: The file has many sentences organised as columns.so i want to check if the 5th column has value same as that of the 4th column.so my sentence is correct only  if 4th and 5th column has same value and that too one section has both RP and /RP coming in both columns.The RP  and /RP tags may not be in adjacent lines.There can be many line in between.I want the count of all the sections that has RP and /RP coming in both columns.In the above example there are 2 sections.But my count is 1 since only first section is in correct format.

Comment: Your description is far from thorough, but I have tried again to interpret what you want. Please see my answer

Comment: Thanks your code worked.Actually i wanted to take the count of properly tagged sentences.The sentence would be properly tagged only if columns 4 and 5 contains same value and it should also contain the RP and /RP tag.Thanks once again.